# JVM: Is it safe to store a BigDecimal as a double in a database?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, jvm, bigdecimal

I am working on an application that requires monetary calculations, so we're using `BigDecimal` to process such numbers.

I currently store the BigDecimals as a string in a PostgreSQL database. It made the most sense to me because I now am sure that the numbers will not lose precision as opposed to when they are stored as a double in the database.

The thing is that I cannot really do a lot of queries for that (i.e 'smaller than X' on a number stored as text is impossible)

For numbers I do have to perform complex queries on, I just create a new column value called indexedY (where Y is the name of the original column). I.e I have amount (string) and indexedAmount (double). I convert amount to indexedAmount by calling `toDouble()` on the BigDecimal instance.

I now just do the query, and then when a table is found, I just convert the string version of the same number to a BigDecimal and perform the query once again (this time on the fetched object), just to make sure I didn't have any rounding errors while the double was in transit (from the application to DB and back to the application)

I was wondering if I can avoid this extra step of creating the indexedY columns.

So my question comes down to this: is it safe to just store the outcome of a BigDecimal as a double in a (PostgreSQL) table without losing precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If BigDecimal is required, I would use a NUMERIC type with as much precision as you need. Eg NUMERIC(20, 20)

However if you only needs 15 digits of precision, using a double in the database might be fine, in which case it should be fine in Java too.

Comment: …if you only need 15 digits of precision, using a `long` would be fine, especially for monetary calculations, which you should do with fix point arithmetic anyway.

Comment: It's for cryptocurrencies as well, some have up to 18 decimals (like Ethereum). Numeric should suffice in that regard. Thanks!